# How to migrate elgg database to wamp server?

Tags: php, elgg

These are the the queries that i found , how can i migrate to wamp server, the directory of my project is `C:/wamp/www/elgg_test/` , if i replace the query with `/var/www/elgg_test/` i am getting a blank page

Database Entries
Change the installation path

UPDATE `elgg_datalists` SET `value` = "/var/www/elgg_test/" WHERE `name` = "path";
Change the data directory`

UPDATE `elgg_datalists` SET `value` = "/var/data/elgg_test/" WHERE `name` = "dataroot";
Change the site URL

UPDATE `elgg_sites_entity` SET `url` = "http://test.myelgg.org/";
Change the filestore data directory

(Only change the first path here!!)
UPDATE elgg_metastrings set string = '/var/data/elgg_test/' WHERE id = (SELECT value_id from elgg_metadata where name_id = (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM elgg_metastrings WHERE string = 'filestore::dir_root') as ms2) LIMIT 1) ;

Answer (score 1):

Read through http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Duplicate_Installation

Make sure to enable mod_rewrite on Apache

Answer (score 0):

Have you made the changes in `engine/setiings.php`? and have you moved the data directory? you do not have to change anything in `elgg_metastrings`, also try upgrading the site.

mostly for moving the site, only changes in the engine/settings.php and db as you have done, are required

```
UPDATE elgg_datalists SET value = "/var/www/elgg_test/" WHERE name = "path"; 

UPDATE elgg_datalists SET value = "/var/data/elgg_test/" WHERE name = "dataroot"; 

UPDATE elgg_sites_entity SET url = "http://test.myelgg.org/";
```

Read it carefully, http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Duplicate_Installation.

Answer (score 0):

You Should be using `C:/wamp/www/elgg_test/` as your path not `/var/www/elgg_test/` if your directory is `C:/wamp/www/elgg_test/`. So Queries will be like:

```
UPDATE elgg_datalists SET value = "C:/wamp/www/elgg_test/" WHERE name = "path"; 

UPDATE elgg_datalists SET value = "C:/wamp/www/elgg_data/" WHERE name = "dataroot"; // create data folder at C:/wamp/www/elgg_data/

UPDATE elgg_sites_entity SET url = "http://localhost/"; // if you are using localhost, else if you are using virtual host update acccrodingly.
```